REST API - ":word" (eg ":predict") vs ":port" (eg ":1000") What is this called?
Tensorflow REST URL endpoints look like this: http://host:port/v1/models/${MODEL_NAME}[/versions/${VERSION}|/labels/${LABEL}]:predict
Where the URL ends in ":predict", rather than in ":1000" a number/port like I would expect. Why does this work? Are there some other example URL endpoints that use this schema of a word rather than a number? I'm having a hard time googling for this concept so would love if stackoverflow can point me to a vocab term I'm missing.

...your example also has a port in it. Not to mention another colon between scheme and host. A colon in the path is just a colon, in the path.

the term is path templating or URI Templates, based on RFC3986  the : is not a reserved character in a path thus allowing it to be used.  You can find an example of this pattern with Microsoft Azure action patterns for their apis  https://github.com/microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/azure/ConsiderationsForServiceDesign.md#action-operations

I'm not confused about the colon (the symbol ":") but about the port being a number vs a word

The linked questions are useful though, thanks

URLs don't end in a port. If there is a non-standard port, that port shows up right after the host (domain), but before the path.
The :predict part of your URL is simply part of the 'path' part of the URL. It doesn't have a special meaning fur URLs generally, but may have a special meaning for the specific API you're working with.
